# Floated <li> width (maintaining aspect ratio)

Tags: css, css-float

I have a `div` of unspecified width (#bottom-bar), absolutely positioned at the bottom of the view-port (stuck to the bottom of the window). Its height is 20% of window height.

Within this `div`, I have a `ul`, with inline-block `li`'s, each with an `a` wrapping an `img` inside them.

You will notice, in the example, that when you size the window vertically, the images within the `li`'s change size as you would expect, but the `a` surrounding the image does not change width.

If you then reload the page, the widths of the `a`'s will be correct...that is, until you resize the page again.

Is there a workaround for this?  I would prefer to not use JS.

Example Page: http://psofe.com/footer_slider

Comment: I don't get it and nothing changes if I reload in Firefox. It happens in Chrome (but it's quite buggy when it comes to necessary repaints on resizing so nothing unusual) but what is displayed in Chrome is fairly different from Firefox (img are separated by a wide space in Fx)

Comment: I now see that the problems in firefox are related, but not entirely the same.  Thank you for pointing this out.  Will rework css, and try again.